# Do all gcc versions support gcc's @file option?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, compiler-options

As far as I remember some older gcc versions don't support the @file option. I am not very sure. Could someone give any pointers related to this?

For reference

```
   @file
   Read command-line options from file.  The options read are inserted
   in place of the original @file option.  If file does not exist, or
   cannot be read, then the option will be treated literally, and not
   removed.

   Options in file are separated by whitespace.  A whitespace
   character may be included in an option by surrounding the entire
   option in either single or double quotes.  Any character (including
   a backslash) may be included by prefixing the character to be
   included with a backslash.  The file may itself contain additional
   @file options; any such options will be processed recursively.
```

Thanks

Comment: The [online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) goes back all the way to version 2.95.3. It might take some time, but easy to check all the versions.

Comment: Also, assuming the option was present in all versions up from a certain release, you can use binary search.

Comment: It seems gcc 4.1.2 doesn't support it.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav, check again. My gcc-4.7.2-8.fc18.x86_64 (Fedora 18) cites in in the manpage under "Overall options". And it works.

Comment: @vonbrand How does your check of gcc-4.7.2 negate PrasoonSaurav's assertions that it doesn't work in gcc-4.1.2? These compilers are 5 years apart.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, there was a statement that it was in gcc-2.95, I remember being quite intrigued by the option in some pre-2 gcc, and it is present in 4.7.2. So I think PrasoonSaurav is mistaken.

Comment: @vonbrand You've misunderstood Joachim's comment.  The **online documentation** for all releases goes back to 2.95, but the existence of **this feature** is not that old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer is wrong.

The mentioned revision ([SVN r107426](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=9d5305381ff11ba5615705672115079ffb7b0750)) is not included in 4.1.x branches. It actually works since 4.2.0, consistent to [the document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options).

Answer (score 3):

This was committed to gcc source here:

```
2005-11-23  Mark Mitchell  <mark@codesourcery.com>

    * doc/invoke.texi: For man pages, include gcc-vers.texi.
    List @file in the option summary.  Include the libiberty
    documentation for @file.
    * gcc.c (main): Call expandargv.
    * Makefile.in (gcc-vers.texi): Define srcdir.
```

According to release [history](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html), this should have made it into GCC 4.1